# NSMutableArray UIButton Press History

Tags: ios, arrays, sdk, uibutton, history

I currently have an array of buttons being generated which works great. Outside of this on touch up inside each button calls on a `-(void)onTouch` function where some math is done to determine an action. This all works great except I would like to store a history of the pressed buttons. I've tried many different ways to create an `NSMutableArray` and store the values of the pressed buttons, but because I can only declare the array within the `-onTouch` action, every time a button is pressed the array is reset so it never remembers more than one move. If I try to declare the array in my header and synthesize it outside I either get the error that nsmutable array is not a compile time thinger or it doesn't store anything (log output is "(null)". Can someone paste in some code on how to declare an array that can store and append the uibutton tags outside of where the uibutton press event happens? I'll post code later tonight if this isn't clear.

Cheers

Comment: Please post your code and the actual compiler errors messages.

Comment: self.myArray = [NSMutableArray array];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *tapCollection;

-(void)viewDidLoad{

   self.tapCollection = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

-(void)onTouch:(id)sender{

   UIButton *btnTapped = (UIButton *)sender;

   [self.tapCollection addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:btn.tag]];
}
```

Comment: You can't add an integer to an array as it's not an object.

Comment: `[self.tapCollection addObject:@(btn.tag)];`

Comment: @Moxy, yes you can. I have had no troubles calling NSInteger[] and converting the button.tag into an array. That being said, the code to do it is a little more involved than addObject:@(button.tag). Ramshad, I'll try your solution and see how she goes. Thanks

Comment: @NessyString That would be a c array. You can't put integers in an NSArray/NSMutableArray unless you wrap them in an NSNumber like rmaddy commented.

Comment: yup.. I just posted the answer quickly and went away... edited now..sorry guys.:)

Comment: Edit again please and rename `btn.tag` to `btnTapped.tag`.

Comment: My mistake I meant NSNumber numberWithInt. I don't have my mac with me at work so I can't look at my code until this afternoon, but I had confirmed this method was working last night, I just couldn't get it to store more than one entry (as stated). Thanks for the involved answers guys, looks promising.

Comment: Thanks Ramshad, worked very well. I edited it slightly for the next person who needs help with this issue. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You need to not only *declare* the array, but also *initialise* it. If you don't initialise, you won't necessarily get a warning, but you will get lots of nil data.

You only want to initialise the array once (as you have noticed) so `viewDidLoad` is a good place to do it. Another good place is in a custom accessor...

```
- (NSMutableArray*)historyArray
{
    if (!_historyArray) {
       _historyArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return _historyArray;
}
```

Now the first time you try to `[self.historyArray addObject:sender]`, the accessor will note the absence of a historyArray, create one and return it. Next time round it won't be recreated as it already exits.